# Что такое регистр?

Tags: терминология, cpu, gdb, процессор

Пытаюсь понять, что такое регистр. Часто наблюдаю табличку `Registers` в `gdb` при отладке. Нашел определение в Интернете:

```
Специализированная ячейка памяти, входящая в состав процессора. Регистры выполняют функции
кратковременного хранения и преобразования данных или команд. На физическом уровне регистр
представляет собой совокупность триггеров, способных хранить один двоичный разряд и связанных
между собой общей системой управления
```

Но особого понимания так и не появилось. Слышал, что регистры используются в `SRAM`. А что они хранят? Для чего нужны? На практике в `gdb` вижу:

```
rax            0x555555555149      93824992235849
```

`rax` это название регистра? А виртуальный адрес как я понимаю указывает на число `93824992235849`? Какая практическая польза от этого. Опишите пожалуйста русским языком.

Comment: почитайте любую книгу по ассемблеру. А по факту - регистры это такая супер-быстрая память, которой при этом не так много, но она находися внутри процессора.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, про быстроту её, тоже наслышан, но вот понять бы, что эти регистры хранят, хотя бы иметь примерное понимание, чтобы в случае чего знал куда копать. А слишком углублённо мне не нужно)

Comment: хранят значение (в данном случае 64-разрядное число)

Comment: именно значения. А как интерпретировать это значение - зависит от программиста. Одно и тоже значение может быть как адресом в памяти, так и просто значением, так и закодированной строкой.

Comment: Регистры хранят значения, над которыми производятся какие либо операции процессором. Со значением из обычной памяти невозможно ничего сделать, даже 1 добавить, не загрузив предварительно в регистр

Comment: Вы, скорее всего слышали, что регистры *построены* как SRAM (т.е. на триггерах), в отличие от DRAM (на конденсаторах). Поэтому они такие быстрые и дорогие, а DRAM -- это в том числе ОЗУ компьютера, которая медленнее регистров, но объемнее.

Comment: Какая практическая польза? Ну регистры это критически важный компонент CPU. Через них производятся все вычисления.

Comment: можно представить регистры как переменные в программировании, за той лишь разницей что число их огранниченно, имена не задаются программистом, а использование их в аргументах, или неявно часто зависит от спецификации процессора и его команд, то же самое можно сказать про флаги процессора (но для их сравнения лучше прибегнуть к аналогии return возвращаемого результата)

Comment: Всем спасибо! Теперь более менее понятно